# How to check update Add in Office everytime?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, outlook-addin, auto-update

I developed an add-in for Outlook. I published her in a file location which users having access. Installation works but now I would like to manage the auto-update. When I publish a new version of my add-in the system don't update my application. Can you help me ? Thanks in advance.

PS: I am developing with Visual Studio 2010 in C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use ClickOnce for deploying Office addins. If you do, you can also set the frequency the program checks for updates.

Go to your `Project Properties > Publish > Updates...` and set the radio button group to the first item: `Check every time the customization runs`.

[image]